# Why using QAbstractTableModel instead of QAbstractListModel?

Tags: qml, qtquick2, datamodel, qabstracttablemodel, qabstractlistmodel

I've implemented `TableView` in QML using `TableViewColumn`s with some roles like this:

```
TableView {
    TableViewColumn {
        role: "role1"
        title: "Role1"
    }
    ...
}
```

It's bound to a C++ model, inherited from `QAbstractListModel` with all the roles defined and I find it perfectly natural.

However, I've found out that there also exists `QAbstractTableModel`, which allows using column indices. I've understood that I should've probably used it, but I prefer **roles to column indices**.

Could someone please explain what is the advantage of using `QAbstractTableModel`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't one unless your using Qt Widgets vs. Qt Quick.

Qt in general has a [Model/View architecture](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html)  and this architecture can be used either with Qt Widgets *or* Qt Quick. Its the same concept in both but the View classes are different between the two especially the table views.

In Qt Widgets you have [QTableView](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtableview.html), this view expects the model data to be layed out in a table (i.e. rows and columns) and as such one would use a sub-class of the QAbstractTableModel to provide it this data.

In Qt Quick however the [TableView](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-tableview.html) type is ***NOT*** a one-to-one copy of the QTableView class. In fact its completely different and it expects the data in any model provided to it to be laied out in a list (i.e. rows but only 1 column) ***NOT*** a table. To achive a table like arragement of data the TableView type uses roles in lue of columns.

So in Qt Widgets one can use the QTableView class and use a sub-class of QAbstractTableModel to provide it data in a table layout (rows and columns) but in Qt Quick one uses the TableView type and uses a sub-class of QAbstractListModel to provide it data in a list layout (rows and only 1 column) but instead of showing only the Qt::DisplayRole in each cell one can declare a different role to be used in each column of the TableView.

Its not so much as one had more value over the other its just that one View type/class expects the data in a different format then the other.

If your sitting there thinking Qt has made this needlessly complicated just know that the table view is the odd duck; if you were talking about a list view the QListView (Qt Widgets) class and the ListView (Qt Quick) type are actually nearly a one-to-one in behaviour, they can both use the same model interchangabley. That is you can put your model in a shared library and use it in either a Qt Quick or Qt Widgets application with no modifications. It should be noted that the same can be achived for QTableView/TableView but the model will have to support both expectations, showing the data as both a table with rows and columns and as a list with rows and roles.

I hope that anwsers your question.

*Until next time think imaginatively and design creatively*